# In org-mode how to disable auto numbering of numbered list?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Here is an example of the text that I want the number of the list items to be frozen, no longer automatically updated in org-mode text.

```
2. List the customer number, customer name, event number, date held, facility
   number, facility name, and estimated audience cost per person (EstCost /
   EstAudience) for events held on 2013, in which the estimated cost per person
   is less than $0.2

Some text...

3. List the customer number, customer name, and total estimated costs for
   Approved events. The total amount of events is the sum of the estimated cost
   for each event. Group the results by customer number and customer name.
```

In the export to PDF or some other operation, the first list item, the '2' above would become '1', and '3' to '1'. I want them to remain what they were.

I tried to search for a solution, but couldn't find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can restart list numbering at any point by inserting a special code like this:

```
1. first list item
18. [@18] Now we continue on 18
19. next

some text...

20. [@20] this is number 20
```

This is documented [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it's there, but it's easy to miss it as it's at the end of long text, and itself is also lengthy: If you want a list to start with a different value (e.g., 20), start the text of the item with [@20]